# Phantom.js / Casper.js with rotating proxy?

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, casperjs, proxy-server

I have a simple goal: load webpages with either `phantom.js` (out of the box) or `casper.js` (nice and easier) but **using proxy and rotate it** from a list if current one is bad (i.e. webpage loads fail or something like that).

I know casper.js has `--proxy` param but it dictates the user to specify only ONE proxy and use it during runtime.

**Question #1 is: how to rotate proxy on the fly programmatically?**

I did some research and found this [node-requester](https://github.com/icodeforlove/node-requester) but it's not integrated with `casper.js`. I tried to extract out just the proxy feature in the [code](https://github.com/icodeforlove/node-requester/blob/master/lib/requester.js) but didn't really understand how it works in the nutshell (I am not that smart I guess).

**So question #2: is there some simple implementation of proxy rotation that works with either `phantom.js` or `casper.js`?**

I prefer to use the fancy `casper.js` though but will go down with `phantom.js` bare as well.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue a while back, I worked with PhantomJS. The solution we ended up with was running PhantomJS as a child process of a larger Java/Scala server which then handled failures and assigned the different proxies when needed (by rerunning with different params in the --proxy arg).

Comment: Its been a couple of years, is there a better solution today?